# issue running a test in Python, via rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

*I have a feeling this will be a quick fix, given that I started coding two weeks ago.  I am try to run a statistical test - a Mantel, looking for a correlation between two distance matrices - in Python, by using a function(?) that has already been written in R, via Rpy2. The R module is "ade4" and it contains "mantel.rtest"*

```
from rpy2 import robjects

import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r('library(ade4)')
**EDIT** rmantel = robjects.r("mantel.rtest")

for i in windownA:

    M1 = asmatrix(identityA[i]).reshape(14,14)

    for j in windownB:

        M2 = asmatrix(identityB[j]).reshape(14,14)

       **EDIT** result = rmantel (M1, M2, nrepet = 9999)
        print result
        print ' '
```

EDIT: this now works!  *"This returns the error: **"AttributeError: 'R' object has no attribute 'mantel'"** which leads me to believe that the object being called here is truncated at the "." (i.e. "mantel" versus the full "mantel.rtest").  I tried reassigning the "mantel.rtest" as an object without a "."  ex)
    rmantel = "mantel.rtest"
and substituting that 
    result = robjects.r.rmantel (M1, M2, nrepet = 9999)
only to receive the error: **"AttributeError: 'R' object has no attribute 'rmantel'"** - so that did not work. Any thoughts as to how I can get around this issue?"*

***New Issue***:  The Mantel test require data in "dist" format, so when I run the edited code, I get the following error **"RRuntimeError: Error in function (m1, m2, nrepet = 99)  : 
  Object of class 'dist' expected"**

So I tried to convert the file to that format and when I print the results, it's the bottom half of a matrix of the correct size, but all fields are filled with "NA"

```
robjects.r('library(ade4)')
rmantel = robjects.r("mantel.rtest")

distify = robjects.r("dist")

for i in windownA:

    M1 = asmatrix(identityA[i]).reshape(14,14)
    print distify(M1)
    MOne = distify(M1, 14)

    for j in windownB:

        M2 = asmatrix(identityB[j]).reshape(14,14)
        print distify(M2)
        MTwo = distify(M2, 14)

        result = rmantel(M1, M2, nrepet = 9999)
        print result
        print ' '
```

i get"

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13

2  NA

3  NA NA

4  NA NA NA

5  NA NA NA NA

6  NA NA NA NA NA

7  NA NA NA NA NA NA

8  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

9  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

11 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

12 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

13 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: as just a note that this is only the relevant part of the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `robjects.r['mantel.rtest']`:

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop.
:from rpy2 import robjects
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r('library(ade4)')
::::::--

In [3]: robjects.r['mantel.rtest']
Out[5]: <RFunction - Python:0xa2aac0c / R:0xac9ec04>
```

This also works:

```
In [8]: robjects.r('mantel.rtest')
Out[8]: <RFunction - Python:0xaf7042c / R:0xac9ec04>
```

**Edit (for the New Issue):**
Since you say `mantel.rtest` requires data in `dist` format, I suppose `M1` and `M2` should be in `dist` format. But `M1` and `M2` appear to be numpy arrays. On the other hand, `MOne` and `MTwo` look like they might be in `dist` format.

So perhaps try

```
result = rmantel(MOne, MTwo, nrepet = 9999)
```

Comment: thanks for your speedy reply.  oddly enough, I edited my code to read as I've show it above and things worked.  unfortunately, now I have another (more idiosyncratic) issue, related to the test I'm trying to run... if you have any insight into this new issue, I would very much appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

From rpy2-2.1.x, the recommended simple way to do it is:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
stats = importr('stats')
ade4 = importr('ade4')

result = ade4.mantel_rtest(stats.dist(M1),
                           stats.dist(M2),
                           nrepet)
```

Comment: thanks for this, I gave this a shot a while back but received the following: "ImportError: No module named packages". 

I've decided to go a different direction, and just reached another impasse, but I'll post that question as a separate one in a few.

Comment: The code is for rpy2-2.1.x. Your other post hints that you are using MSWindows (and there is no release for it in the 2.1.x series yet).

Comment: very true, I'm confined to Windows 7 for time being

Comment: @vehicularlambslaughter : The 2.0.x series was the first attempt; 2.1.x is significantly simpler and better (not only according to myself, that's what I heard and read). Hopefully there will be progress on the MSWindows front with rpy2 some time in the future.